# How do I get rid of Command Block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a Rapid Pulser connected to a Command Block, coordinates to the middle of nowhere, and when I get even 300 blocks close to it, it warps me to the coordinates. How can I destroy these blocks without getting close?

Answer (score 3):

If you know some coordinates around it then you can use this:

/setblock x y z air 0 replace

Answer (score 2):

type in /gamemode spectator

Next fly inside the command block
then do /setblock ~ ~ ~ air 0 replace